# How to differentiate by case when sorting a DataTable?

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable, ado.net

I notice that when sorting the rows in a datatable by a particular column using a dataview (in C#), the sorting method appears to not differentiate between upper and lowercase strings. Is there a way to sort a datatable by a column in a manner that strings are seen as different based on their case?

```
        DataTable Dt18 = new DataTable();
        Dt18.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
        Dt18.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
        Dt18.Rows.Add(0, "Indocin");
        Dt18.Rows.Add(1, "indocin");
        Dt18.Rows.Add(17, "Indocin");
        Dt18.Rows.Add(2, "Hydralazine");
        Dt18.Rows.Add(3, "Combivent");
        DataView view = new DataView(Dt18);
        view.Sort = "Drug asc";
        DataTable dtSorted = view.ToTable();
```

When sorting by the column titled "Drug", "Indocin" is seen as being the same as "indocin"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set **CaseSensitive** property of Dt18 as below:

```
DataTable Dt18 = new DataTable();
Dt18.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
Dt18.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
Dt18.Rows.Add(0, "Indocin");
Dt18.Rows.Add(1, "indocin");
Dt18.Rows.Add(17, "Indocin");
Dt18.Rows.Add(2, "Hydralazine");
Dt18.Rows.Add(3, "Combivent");
Dt18.CaseSensitive = true;
DataView view = new DataView(Dt18);
view.Sort = "Drug asc";
DataTable dtSorted = view.ToTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

set `view.CaseSensitive = false;`
true if the comparison is case-sensitive, otherwise false.